# adding xml-stylesheet in existing xml file at the seconed line

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have xml string file in which I want to add xml-stylesheet at the seconed line of xml string file.
but the code given below give me the output like this:
first the xml- string file and then append xml-stylesheet at the end of xml string file but I want the style-sheet at the seconed line of my xml-string.please suggest me how should I do this.
thanks.

my code is:

```
public class StringToDocumentToString {

public static void main(String[] args)
        throws TransformerConfigurationException {
    String xmlstring = null;
    String filepath = "E:/C-CDA/MU2_CDA_WORKSPACE/AddingStylesheetTOxml/documentfile.txt";
    final String xmlStr = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n"
            + "<Emp id=\"1\"><name>Pankaj</name><age>25</age>\n"
            + "<role>Developer</role><gen>Male</gen></Emp>";


    Document doc2 = convertStringToDocument(xmlStr);
    Document doc1 = null;
    try {
        doc1 = addingStylesheet(doc2);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String str = convertDocumentToString(doc1);
    System.out.println(str);
}

private static <ProcessingInstructionImpl> Document addingStylesheet(
        Document doc) throws TransformerConfigurationException,
        ParserConfigurationException {

    ProcessingInstructionImpl pi = (ProcessingInstructionImpl) doc
            .createProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet",
                    "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"my.stylesheet.xsl\"");
    Element root = doc.createElement("root-element");
    doc.appendChild(root);

    doc.insertBefore((Node) pi, root);
    return doc;

}

private static String convertDocumentToString(Document doc) {
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer;
    try {
        transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        // below code to remove XML declaration
        // transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION,
        // "yes");
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
        String output = writer.getBuffer().toString();
        return output;
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

private static Document convertStringToDocument(String xmlStr) {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlStr)));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return doc;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `Element root = doc.createElement("root-element");` creates a new element named `root-element` and when you call `doc.appendChild(root);` you're actually appending it to the end of the document. So after these two statement, your document would be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Emp id="1">
    <name>Pankaj</name>
    <age>25</age>
    <role>Developer</role>
    <gen>Male</gen>
</Emp>
<root-element/>
```

Then you have `doc.insertBefore((Node) pi, root);` which causes to add the stylesheet processing instruction just before this newly added element.

To fix this, you have to retrieve a pointer to your document root element (instead of adding a new element named `root-element`) and then add the pi just before it. This would be possible by calling `getDocumentElement()` method of the `doc` object. So in order to fix the problem you just need to use the following code in your `main` method:

```
Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
doc.insertBefore((Node) pi, root);
```